# Copy data from cObject in typoscript

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I would like to copy the values from a cObject data attribute in typoscript:

```xml
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.datei" data="{link}" />
```

in ts I can get it with:

```
lib.datei = TEXT
lib.datei.current = 1
```

it works, but I can not copy or reference  it to another ts-object:

```
lib.test = TEXT
lib.test < lib.datei
```

if the value of lib.datei is a plain Text it works...
where am I wrong...??

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the context. the Context a typoscript object is valid and has a specific value.

if you call some typoscript rom a fluid viewhelper that specific object has a value. Inside that object you also can access global values.
But you have no access from another (temporarily) object called in another fluid-viewhelper call.

Neither can you access in your page rendering process on that specific value as that object has no input in that context.